# Ninject contextual binding magic

Tags: ninject

I have a bit of a strange situation with regard to my bindings.

I have a few event sources, and classes that want to subscribe to them. I'll have different instances of the sources (although they will all be the same classes), but the types of the subscribers might change between different classes.

My approach so far is something like this:

```
public interface ISubscribeTo<T> where T : ISubscribable
{
  void Subscribe(T eventSource);
}

public interface ISubscribable {}
```

I want to have any type that is an `ISubscribeTo<T>` have an instance of the `ISubscribable` passed through to it on activation.

This is pretty trivial when I use an `ActivationStrategy` to wire these things up.

The complication I have is that the `ISubscribeTo<T>`s vary depending on what class I'm activating.

In my `ActivationStrategy`, I have a call into the kernel's `GetAll` method, but I'd like to somehow only get instances that are already activated for the request.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the event brokers. They make it very easy to subscribe to events from other components without adding an own mechanism. See [the tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/bbvcommon/wiki/EventBrokerTutorial)

```
https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.bbveventbroker
```